# Adding rules dynamically into drools engine

Tags: dynamic, jboss, drools

I have a standalone java application which will interact with my web application running on node. I am trying to add new rules dynamically through web UI. So far I am unable to figure it out, how to create and add rules. Any suggestions for the right direction would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036973 so the following is basically a duplicate of my answer to that question...

It's probably best to just look at the Drools examples source code. For instance the [KieFileSystem example](https://github.com/gratiartis/drools/blob/master/drools-examples-api/kiefilesystem-example/src/main/java/org/drools/example/api/kiefilesystem/KieFileSystemExample.java) shows how to create a rule from a String and launch a session which includes it.

The essentials are that you create a `KieServices`, which contains a virtual file system. You then add rules to that file system. A little bit like the following:

```java
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
kfs.write("src/main/resources/my/rules/therule.drl", "The source code of the rule");
KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);
kb.buildAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can add multiple Compiled rule DRL files like 
knowledgebuilder.add(new ByteArrayResource(compiledDRL.getBytes()),ResourceType.DRL);


Get all the knowledgePackages and fire the all rules 

knowledgeBase kbase = knowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
kbase.addknowledgePackages(knowledgeBuilder.getKnowledgePackages());

knowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefullKnowledgeSession();
ksession.insert(inputObject);
ksession.fireAllRules();
ksession.dispose();
```